# ffmpeg encoding run a shell command

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

How do i run this file

```
infile ="video.avi"
tmpfile="video_tmp.mp4"
outfile="video.mp4"
options="-vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
   -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
   -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
   -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
         -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
   -qmax 51 -qdiff 4"

ffmpeg -y -i "$infile" -an -pass 1 -threads 2 $options "$tmpfile"

ffmpeg -y -i "$infile" -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96k -pass 2 -threads 2 $options "$tmpfile"

qt-faststart "$tmpfile" "$outfile"
```

Taken from here https://gist.github.com/vadimii/4621929

Shell commands is well out of my scope any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Save, `chmod +x script` and `./script`

Comment: it is a shell script - save it to a file and then execute it using your shell interpreter e.g. `bash file.sh`

Comment: so the command would just be ./file video_one.mov output.mp4

Comment: It is not taking any parameter, so just `./file` is enough. To have one parameter, use `infile=$1` and then execute with `./file video_one...`. In general, try to ask more clearly so we can know what you exactly want to do with this script.

Comment: sorry i have ffmpeg installed and i am just trying to encode for H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps and i ended up at this script so i am trying to get it to run.

Comment: Yes, but do you want to execute it with parameters? That to say, do you want to indicate the input file as well as the output file?

Comment: yes i want both input file to encode and output file

Comment: There is no reason to use so many options. That's what the [x264 presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#a2.Chooseapreset) are for. Everything after your bitrate (which should be renamed to `-b:v`) can be replaced by `-preset slow`. Adding `-movflags +faststart` as an output option on your second pass will allow you to skip usage of `qt-faststart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what has been written in comments:

```
infile =$1
tmpfile="video_tmp.mp4"
outfile=$2
options="-vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
   -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
   -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
   -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
         -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
   -qmax 51 -qdiff 4"

ffmpeg -y -i "$infile" -an -pass 1 -threads 2 $options "$tmpfile"

ffmpeg -y -i "$infile" -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96k -pass 2 -threads 2 $options "$tmpfile"

qt-faststart "$tmpfile" "$outfile"
```

To execute it:

- Save this file as let's say `my_script`.
- Give it executing permissions: `chmod +x my_script`.
- Execute it givin parameters as follows:

  ```
  ./my_script input_file output_file
  ```

or

```
/bin/bash my_script input_file output_file
```

Comment: thanks that run it but i get the error : No such file or directory
last atom in file was not a moov atom i think ill try find a good gui

Comment: If you are adding the parameters without its path, make sure they are in the same path of the script. Otherwise, put their full path.